# Prove $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^k}=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, hypergeometric-function

How to prove that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^k}=2 \,\,?$$

A plot shows that the values seem to quickly converge to $2$.

[image]

Cannot exclude a duplicate but couldn't find it in the search.

Comment: Would you please provide more context?

Comment: Try $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!^\infty}\to \frac 1{0!^\infty}+\frac1{1!^\infty}+\frac1{2!^\infty}\to \frac 11+\frac11+0+0+…=2$$ Essentially, all terms after $n=2$ approach 0 while the “infinite power” of $1$ approaches to $1$.

Comment: Show for $k\ge 1$ that it is between  $2+2^{-k}$ and  $2+2^{-k+1}$

Comment: I would think you can exchange limit and sum because $\frac{1}{n!^k}$ is dominated by $\frac{1}{n!}$, for each $k$? (dominated convergence) (or perhaps better thought of as monotone convergence in this case)

Comment: **Hint :** This is $$\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{(n!)^k}$$
Show that you can interchange the two limits by a uniform convergence argument.

Comment: Yet another approach: show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(n!)^k}\leq\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n!}\right)^k$ and that the inner sum on the RHS is less than 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $n \geq 2$ you have obviously
$$\frac 1{n!} \leq \frac 1{2^{n-1}}$$

Now squeeze:

$$2 < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(n!)^k} < 2+\underbrace{\sum_{\color{\blue}{n=2}}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{(n-1)k}}}_{=\frac 1{2^k}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{(n-2)k}}<\frac 1{2^k}\sum_{\color{\blue}{n=0}}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{n}}}$$

Comment: +1 for not needing subtleties like uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration, but not necessarily a rigorous proof:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!^k}= \frac1{0!^k}+\frac1{1!^k}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n!^k} =2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n!^k}$$

Now we need to show that:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n!^k}=0 $$

For $n\ge2,n!>1$ and raising an $x>1$ to higher powers will give increasingly larger numbers, but taking the reciprocal of those increasingly larger numbers will produce numbers getting closer to $0$. Since the power here is infinite, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}n!^k\to\infty$ and $\frac1{n!^k}\to 0$

So $$2+\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n!^k} =2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty 0=2$$